# Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `false` in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings, render

I am trying to create a list and make it clickable so that once i click on an item i get redirect to another page

here is the render method

```
 render() {
const quesItems = this.state.questions.map((question, i) => {
  return (
    <li key={this.props.account.id === question.expID}>
      <a href={`/ans/${question.id}`}> {question.description}</a>
    </li>
  );
});
return (
  <div>
    <h1> Answer the questions here!</h1>
    <ul>
      {quesItems}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

}

However i am getting the following warning when i click on any item on the list. How can i fix it?

```
index.js:2177 Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `false`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
```

Comment: The inspector is telling you the answer. what is `this.props.account.id` returning? Do a console.log of that.

Comment: Please mark answers as accepted when you think it solved your issue by pressing the little checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `this.props.account.id === question.expID` returns a boolean value. The `key` prop should usually not be a boolean (there are only two distinct values). Probably `quesItems` contains multiple items whose `expID` does not equal `this.props.account.id`. All those will render with `key={false}` which is not allowed. The correct value for a key prop is probably just the question `id`;

**EDIT**: Based on the suggestion of @Colin I added the filtering logic. Also see [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
render() {
    const questions = this.state.questions.filter(question => question.expID === this.props.account.id)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Answer the questions here!</h1>
            <ul>
                {questions.map(({id, description}) => (
                    <li key={id}>
                        <a href={`/ans/${id}`}>{description}</a>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: From the OP, the key should be `expID`

Comment: @AnilRedshift Maybe, maybe not. This is just a guess. From the code OP posted both could be correct as a question seems to have both a `expID` and a `id` property. The important point is that it has to be unique.

Comment: @trixn but i need this expression which returns boolean as im comparing the id of the person who is logged in with the id of the expert if they are equal then i want all the data from the database belonging to this id

Comment: @MarwaA. Okay but then you should still not assign the result of that expression to the `key` prop. How do you use that information when assigned to `key`? A key has to be unique among all siblings of the same type so react can differentiate them.

Comment: @trixn then how am i supposed to fix this issue?

Comment: @MarwaA. I don't really understand what you are expecting to happen if you assign a boolean to the `key` prop. That does for sure not result in fetching data from a database. Where are these data located? Do you need to make an api call to get them? Give some more insight as your question does not reflect what you are now asking for.

Comment: @MarwaA. why don't you `filter` first and then `map`?

Comment: @MarwaA. Is it that what you want? Only render those questions where the current user is an expert for that question? Then Colin is right. You just have to filter the list of questions before rendering them.

Comment: @Colin im very new to reactJS can you please give me a hint on how to apply a filter?

Comment: @MarwaA. This is pure javascript. Nothing specifically related to react. See my updated answer.

Comment: @MarwaA trixn updated his answer, it should help you out.

Comment: `({id, description})` do that to skip passing `item` then doing `item.id` ?

Comment: @Omar Yes that is inline object destructuring. It saves you from repeatedly adding `item.` when all you need are its properties. You can do that with every function parameter that is an object. I love that language feature and make heavy use of it.